# Сверстать в 3 колонки на div

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Необходимо сверстать так, как на изображении. Текст слева, текст права и кнопка по середине. Я сверстал, но так убого, что страшно показывать.

Если возможно, то без таблиц и без использования CSS3.

[image]

Comment: Что имеете в виду под "без использования CSS3"?

Comment: например без использования тега column-count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.column-l{ float: left; width: 33%; }
.column-r{ float: right; width: 33%; }
.column-c{ display: inline-block; width: 33%; }
```

```html
<div>
   <div class="column-c">center</div>
   <div class="column-l">left</div>
   <div class="column-r">right</div>
</div>
```